# Magento 2 Add Category Tree Renderer Input With Modal Button

Tags: category, adminhtml, magento-2.1, ui-form

I am trying to place the category input for my custom form using uicomponent form.

[image]

I am able to create dropdown but how I can create the button and open a new modal from it?

Can I create a **button** using uicomponent and **open a modal** from it.
I want a button **instead** of **new category** I want to add **select products button** and want to add show **list** of products from **selected** categories in grid.

Here is the xml for creating the category input

```
<field name="parent">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Category</item>
          <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
          <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
          <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
           <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
           <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
           <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
           <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
           <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
           <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
           <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
           <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
             </item>
      </item>
     </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: Until I can understand what's in there and maybe come up with an answer, I can recommend you to take a look at `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Categories` class. It is the one that adds the category tree selector to the product add/edit screen. Maybe you have more luck understanding what's in there.

Comment: @Marius Ya looking at same thing looks thats the best way to do it.

Comment: Hey I think adding modifiers is used only for product form and its very difficult to add it for custom model after looking it for about 3 days I have gone nuts. I just get Invalid UI Component element name: 'category_mapping_form'

Comment: How are the selected options work here?

Answer (score 3):

This code below working with me:

```
     <container>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group</item>
        </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="category_ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Categories</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category 1</item>
                                <item name="optgroup" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                                        <item name="is_active" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category 1.1</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                                <item name="is_active" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category 2</item>
                            </item>
                    </item>
                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_ids</item>
                   </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </container>
```

This is result:

[image: Demo]

> **Note:** With item options you should change `xsi:type="object"` and
>   declare a Class for it.

I hope it was helpful !

Comment: my concern is not how I should create the tree. My Question is to create a button beside the drop down as shown in my screen shot and open a modal from it and to show list of products grid in it.

Comment: How to get selected options in this ?