# How to add new category button in Custom Module edit form in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category-products

Want to add **New Category** Button like **product edit** Category selection.

[image]

Comment: Question has already been added for this although I was also unable to get the answer for it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147308/magento-2-add-category-tree-renderer-input-with-modal-button

Comment: please check this link [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157459/how-to-add-category-tree-structure-like-product-edit-add-in-custom-module-magent)