# How to add Category tree structure like product edit/add in custom module Magento 2 [Solved]

Tags: magento2, category-tree

Hope you all doing well , i have solved the both Question posted by me .

[how to add Category tree structure like product edit/add in custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154582/how-to-add-category-tree-structure-like-product-edit-add-in-custom-module)

[How to add new category button in Custom Module edit form in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154888/how-to-add-new-category-button-in-custom-module-edit-form-in-magento2)

to create category tree first of we create Edit Form Layout

custom_custom_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="article_form"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

create uiComponent file article_form.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">article_form.article_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">article_form.article_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">article Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">article_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Sample\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Simple\Edit\Button\Save</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="article_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">article_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">article_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="article_cate">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">group</item>
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <modal name="create_category_modal">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">modal</item>
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">New Category</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="state" xsi:type="string">!index=create_category:responseStatus</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="create_category">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/insert-form</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string"></item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="render_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render_handle/handle/custom_category_create/buttons/1/"/>
                        <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">new_custom_form</item>
                        <item name="externalProvider" xsi:type="string">new_custom_form.new_custom_form_data_source</item>
                        <item name="toolbarContainer" xsi:type="string">${ $.parentName }</item>
                        <item name="formSubmitType" xsi:type="string">ajax</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </modal>
        <container name="container_category_ids">
            <field name="category_ids">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">article_details</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="create_category_button">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string">New Category</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-small</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/components/button/container</item>
                        <item name="actions" xsi:type="array" >
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">article_form.article_form.article_cate.create_category_modal</item>
                                <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">toggleModal</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">article_form.article_form.article_cate.create_category_modal.create_category</item>
                                <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">render</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">article_form.article_form.article_cate.create_category_modal.create_category</item>
                                <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">resetForm</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="additionalForGroup" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">article_details</item>
                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">insideGroup</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="article_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">KnowledgeBase Information</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="openOnShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="article_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">article_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Title</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

create uiComponent file custom_category_create.xml which is handle New Category Ui Form .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="new_custom_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

now create Uicomponent new category form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">new_custom_form.new_custom_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">new_custom_form.new_custom_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">new_custom_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CreateCategory</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="ajaxSaveType" xsi:type="string">simple</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="new_custom_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\NewCategoryDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">new_custom_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/category/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="data">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="messages">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/messages</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Name</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.name</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="parent">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Parent Category</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data.parent</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where I can Add these files in custom module

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question but an answer to two other questions. Please post this as an answer to the other two questions instead of posting it as a question.