# How I add Category chooser in custom module in backend magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, category, catalog, forms

Anyone Help me please how I create category chooser in custom module in magento 2

[image]

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Thanks for reply I need same category chooser in my custom module

Comment: Just the ui select ?

Comment: Can You please send me the complete process I tried with ui but not work

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157459/how-to-add-category-tree-structure-like-product-edit-add-in-custom-module-magent

Comment: Can you please tell me where I add custom_custom_edit.xml files and article_form.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79139/discussion-between-rahul-katoch-and-priyank).

Comment: Please help anyone I am not getting any solution

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <field name="category_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\Form\Categories\Options</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```